# App Script Array from Named Ranges

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 2 named ranges within a sheet that I would like to extract only the data from cells containing data. The way it is now it will pull even empty cells into the array. Is there a way to do this with something like getActiveRange using named ranges in the sheet?

Not sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: You can just use getRange(....).getValues() and then filter the array to remove empty fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially 2 basic ways to do this.

1) Use `.getValues()` to pull a 2D array of values. Then iterate through using a `for()` loop combined with an `if(){}else{}` statement to check for empty values. If the value is not empty, `.push()` to a new array.

2) Use `.getValues()` to pull a 2D array of values. Use `.filter()` to clean your array. `.filter()` returns a new array so you will want to set this as a `var`. You can then use that `var` as you would any other array. You can `.filter()` using a condition in the `()` or set a function that performs an operation and then pass that function to `.filter()`, ie. `.filter(myFunction)`.

Guide included here on option 2: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

You can look for more guidance on proper iteration using `for() {` loops through the same sight or here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks! If the length of the data in the columns will possibly vary from column to column, would it be better to create an array for each column that has data and iterate through the column and then move to the ncolumns all had the same number of rows it would be easier, but I am trying to complicate this obviously.

Comment: How is your data collected? Is your data grouped by row or by column? The simplest way for data processing is to have each data-point for the same subject be the columns while each subject with data being a new row.

Comment: Let's say for instance that you're taking form submissions, each new submission would be a new row with their responses fitting to each column. There will also be a most-filled column by the virtue of the submission existing so you can iterate through this most-filled column and reference other cells in that row by calling the `n` column at `i` row.

Comment: I am trying to create a spreadsheet that creates a form upon submission for someone to create tests. SOme columns will be multiple choice options and another column field be a paragraph type of answer. I want to create something like the Google I/O summit 2013 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38H7WpsTD0M I know they did this a different way, just trying to get my head around the process.

Comment: To clarify, you want a Google Form to be created _from_ a GAS file using data from Google Sheets?
I am not familiar with this process/ style. You can find more information on this order of operations in the [GAS for Forms Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/).

Taking a cursory glance at the reference, you can create forms on the fly and you would, _theoretically_, be able to use variables pulled from any other part of the Google environment for what you want to create.

Comment: Not sure why I want to reinvent the wheel, but this uses values in rows and I wanted to use the columns for the building of the form. I am assuming it is just a matter of swapping out column length for row length and iterating through the rows in a column. Pretty cool though.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXUsW6VRQak